# Display javascript variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a variable with this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="MyEdit">Money</div>
```

JS:

```
var price1 = 0;
var current_value=document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML;

if (current_value == "msc" or current_value == "phd") {
    price1 = 150;
}
else {
    price1 = 250;
}

document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = price1;
```

Any tips as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Comment: It's a var now, and the guy who answered told me to open a new one if it did not do what I needed. :P

Comment: is the var price1 in global scope? does window.price1 contain the value when you access it from the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if is wrong. There is no operator `or`. In javascript operator or is declared with `||`

You can read more for logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Try

```
var price1 = 0;

if ((current_value == "msc") || (current_value == "phd")) {
    price1 = 150;
}
else {
    price1 = 250;
}
```

Also i suppose that above this block of code you initialize somewhere `current_value`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5sPgs/1/)

Comment: price1 should be initialized even with the broken if

Comment: @cschuff price1 is initialized to 0. The OP dont gine the declaration of current_value which i suppose is somewhere above with the rest of the code

Comment: well, you are right. if setting the innerHTML is executed on the same 'thread' it will break. an uninitialized 'current_value' will not break anything though.